# Error from passing workbook object to another function (Run-time "Automation error")

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of functions that is meant to read data from various worksheets in a separate workbook. The main routine uses a loop to go through various sheet names and within the function two levels down, it looks into the workbook to grab data. I am getting `runtime error '-2147023174' (800706ba) Automation error` at various points in this function, and am wondering where the error lies.

```
Sub mainRoutine()
    'opens workbook and runs makeFile function on a loop
    Dim wbOBJ As Workbook, oFile As integer
    Set wbOBJ = Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    For k = 1 To 20                             
        makeFile myBox.List(k), wbOBJ
    Next k  
    wbOBJ.Saved = True
    wbOBJ.Close
End Sub

Function makeFile(ShtName As String, ByRef wbOBJ as Workbook)
    'calls various procedures from which to collect data
    'and passes workbook object along
    debug.print wbOBJ.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value
    printInfoA(ShtName)
    printInfoB(ShtName, wbOBJ)
End Function

Function printInfoB(ShtName as String, ByRef wbOBJ as Workbook)
    'assigns object to a sheet inside the other workbook, collects data
    Dim wsOBJ As Worksheet
    Set wsOBJ = wbOBJ.Sheets(ShtName)
    For j = 1 to 10
        Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j,1) = wsObj.Cells(j, 1)
    Next j
End Function
```

Even in the `makeFile` function, the error pops up on the `debug.print` line, even though the `debug.print` works, and produces the correct value.
If I suppress that line, the same error will instead occur in the `mainRoutine` on the `wbOBJ.Saved = True` line. What is causing these errors?

(Note that I originally tried to organize it this way, instead of having the workbook open and close everytime I ran the `printInfoB` function, as I am trying to increase speed.)

Comment: Your functions have no return values. Why use functions then instead of subs? Also, `printInfoB(ShtName, wbOBJ)` won't work, as it is expected that you handle the (non-existant) return value. Try `printInfoB ShtName, wbOBJ`, with no parentheses.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Excel 2013, runs fine (after correcting the above mentioned error). What does printinfoA do? Are you sure you are not closing anything or not setting any objects to nothing?

Comment: I fixed the function calls; didn't affect the issue. Yeah printA is just a string of print commands to file #1. Nowhere do I assign any Empty values nor close, until that very end

Comment: I'm baffled. Any other code running, any other workbook interfering? Custom add-ins running in the background? Try it on another machine, see if the issue persists. Sorry, I can't help you, as I can't reproduce the problem. For me it runs withouth problems. :(

Comment: I got it to work after passing the wsObj instead of wbObj and messing with some other things, so it's all good now. Thanks for your help. What is generally best practice for passing objects. I.e. would it be better in my mainRoutine sub to actually extract everything out of a wsObj into an array, and then pass that? Or does it matter.

Comment: I don't think it makes much of a difference. You are basically passing only pointers, so as long as every object is still accessible, it should make no difference. But that is just theory.